# Hook to receive window created and destroyed notification

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, hook

I use RegisterWindowMessage("SHELLHOOK") to register for window create and destroy events. My code is written in C#. The code works perfectly when I'm debugging the code. But when I run the program without debugging, I'm not getting WndProc messages like I used to get while debugging. Does Windows block the hook?

```
class ShellHook:NativeWindow
{
    public ShellHook(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        if (Win32.RegisterShellHookWindow(this.Handle))
        {
            WM_ShellHook    = Win32.RegisterWindowMessage("SHELLHOOK");
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_ShellHook)
        {
            switch((ShellEvents)m.WParam)
            {
                    //m.lparam
                case ShellEvents.HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED:
                    if (windowCreatedEvent != null)
                    {
                        windowCreatedEvent(m.LParam);
                    }
                    break;

                case ShellEvents.HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED:
                    if (windowDestroyedEvent != null)
                    {
                        windowDestroyedEvent(m.LParam);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

This is how I start my wpf app.

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
    MainWindow mainWindowView;

    public App()
    {
        Startup += new StartupEventHandler(App_Startup);
    }

    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        mainWindowView = new MainWindow();
        MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        mainWindowView.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
        mainWindowView.ShowDialog();
    }
 }
```

My MainWindowViewModel Constructor is as follows:

```
 public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        EnumWindows(new EnumWindowsProc(EnumTheWindows), IntPtr.Zero);
        System.Windows.Forms.Form f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
        ShellHook shellHookObject = new ShellHook(f.Handle);
        shellHookObject.windowCreatedEvent += shellHookObject_windowCreatedEvent;
        shellHookObject.windowDestroyedEvent += shellHookObject_windowDestroyedEvent;
    }
```

Comment: Post code, that will be helpful

Comment: Are you creating a shell extension? Are you calling the `RegisterShellHookWindow` function? Are you checking the return codes of all the functions you call for errors?

Comment: Im not creating a shell extension. I just wanted to make a task bar and since I need notifications of window create and destroy,I called the RegisterShellHookWindow function.But the interesting part is that I'm getting the notifications while debugging but not when I run the app without debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the NativeWindow to Form and it looks like its working now. Guys please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The API you're using is essentially a private one, not intended for public use. The documentation calls that out rather explicitly at the top. It's also fairly clear if you think about the name and description of the function: it is for *shell* windows. Are you a shell window? No, because you're not on the Windows Shell team. In fact, you're not even writing a shell extension. So you really shouldn't be using the API at all. Of course, if you must, you're going to have to give it an actual window that at least can pretend to be a shell window.

Comment: This app is a test one. But my main application is a shell window Cody Gray

Comment: But my shell application should have the capability to dispatch messages on window create and window destroy isnt it? My application is not a full fledged shell app as of now. So any ideas?